# Crystal Reports intermittent OutOfMemoryException / Win32Exception The handle is invalid

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

When running a Crystal report, it sometimes throws this error (more details below):

> OutOfMemoryException
> or
> Win32Exception: The handle is invalid

I've been encountering this problem for a month now, I tried everything to fix it like minimizing the load of data but I couldn't solve it.

This bug shows when the desktop was not restarted for 3 days but if the desktop was restarted the bug disappears. Please people with great minds help me thanks.

Code:

```
private void Print(string querySTR, string printerName, bool isShort)
    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        DataSet Ds = null;
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = null;
        try
        {
            PrintModule prntM = new PrintModule();
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(prntM.conn);
            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(querySTR, conn);

            Ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(Ds, "Data");

            if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("No Batch found to print.");
            }


            if (isShort)
            {
                cryRpt.Load("Template4SHORT.rpt");
            }
            else
            {
                cryRpt.Load("Template4LONG.rpt");
            }

            cryRpt.SetDataSource(Ds);

         
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.DissociatePageSizeAndPrinterPaperSize = true;
            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PrinterName = printerName;

            cryRpt.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape;
            cryRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 1, 1);
            
    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR IN PRINT FUNCTION " + ex.ToString());
            Logger.Error("ERROR IN PRINT FUNCTION " + ex.Message, "PRINTMCONTROLLER");
        }
        finally
        {
            Ds.Dispose();
            cryRpt.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```

Error details:

- `OutOfMemoryException`:

  > ```
  > ERROR IN PRINT FUNCTION System.OutOfMemoryException: Out of memory. 
  >    at System.Drawing.GraphicsCheckErrorStatus(Int32 status)
  >    at System.Drewing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttrs, DrawImageAbort callback, IntPtr callbackData) 
  >    at System.Drewing.Graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, Int32 srcX, Int32 srcY, Int32 srcWidth, Int32 srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRender.draw_Imagelnstance(ImageObjectInstance imageInst, Graphics g) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRender.draw_ReportObjectInstance(ReportObjectInstance instance, Graphics g, Rectangle clipRect) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRender.draw_SectionInstance(SectionInstance section, Graphics g, Rectangle clipRect) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageRender.Render(PageObject page, Graphics g, Graphics device_g) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.Shared.PrintingHelper.PrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e, PageObject page, PrintLayoutSettings layoutSettings, Int32& currentPageNumber, Int32& currentHorizontalPageNumber) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintPageEventHandler(Object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e) 
  >    at System.Drawing.printing.PrintDocument.OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e) 
  >    at System.Drawing.printing.PrintDocument._OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
  >    at System.Drawing.printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document) 
  >    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document) 
  >    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
  >    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collected, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collected, Int32 startPageN, Int32 EndPageN) 
  >    at VID.Business_Layer.PrintMController.Print(String querySTR, String printerName, Boolean isShort) in C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VRR-ID_Printing\VID\Business Layer\PrintMController.cs:line 771
  > ```
  >
  > [image]
- `Win32Exception` The handle is invalid:

  > ```
  > ERROR IN PRINT FUNCTION System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The handle is invalid 
  >    at System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController.OnStartPage(PrintDocument document, PrintPageEventArgs e) 
  >    at System.Drawing.printing.PrintController.PrintLoop(PrintDocument document) 
  >    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController.Print(PrintDocument document) 
  >    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument.Print()
  >    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collected, Int32 startPageN, Int32 endPageN) 
  >    at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(Int32 nCopies, Boolean collected, Int32 startPageN, Int32 EndPageN) 
  >    at VID.Business_Layer.PrintMController.Print(String querySTR, String printerName, Boolean isShort) in C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\VRR-ID_Printing\VID\Business Layer\PrintMController.cs:line 771
  > ```
  >
  > [image]

Comment: Did you tried this in another Desktop and see if the error persists.

Comment: yes, i deployed this on 2 desktop and they both get this error.

Comment: @vcs hmm.. is there a way to measure or to identify if the application that i'd made is capable on running on a decent built desktop?? i'm new on software developing.

Answer (score 0):

Its Printer's Issue not with crystal report, Try install proper drivers and also set the default printer, debug your code and check if its picking the name correct when you call Print(...) method.

Comment: take a look at these

http://i.imgur.com/Eu5alhd.jpg

i think it's inside the printername,
and also i'd set the printer as default.

Comment: tell me if you have other solutions, please i want to fix this as soon as possible..

Comment: DareDevil will it make conflict if in my development the crystal report's page setting's printer name is "Oce VarioStream 6100 PCL V4.00" then in the deployment dekstop the name of the printer name is "Oce VarioStream 6100 PCL V4.00 Printer1"?

Comment: Did you see where exactly it breaks out. The most inner function which throws exception

Comment: In catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR IN PRINT FUNCTION " + ex.ToString());
            Logger.Error("ERROR IN PRINT FUNCTION " + ex.Message, "PRINTMCONTROLLER");
        } block see the inner exception by collapsing the "ex" tree